# Google cloud SQL postgres error permission denied for table

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm new to GCP and Cloud SQL.  For the instance I'm trying to access the tables, I created a new User and selected "Build-in authentication".  Its my understanding this User would have **cloudsqlsuperuser** root access.

I think with this access, the User can only create databases but not query (SELECT) existing tables?

I tried querying one of the tables and get "*error permission denied for table*".  I don't have access to the postgres User, but I thought since I can add Users I would also be able to grant privilege to the User so can do SELECT statements.

Is there a privilege I can set for the new User so can do SELECT without having postgress access?

Answer (score 1):

Try the SQL code shown below to grant SELECT rights to a user in Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL:

```
-- Grant SELECT on a specific table
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE schema_name.table_name TO username;

-- Grant SELECT on all tables in a schema
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO username;
```

Replace schema_name, table_name, and username with the names of the users you want to offer SELECT access to. You can also use * to allow access to all tables.

Hope it works :)